# How to create Lists (or Array) of channels in Haskell, like Go

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to compare Haskell with Go for some concurrency examples, the following code is a simple map-reduce example in Go by using Goroutines and channels. The following Go code calculates the sum of squares:

> 1^2+2^2+3^2....1024^2

In order to test the performance of Go and Haskell, I repeat calculate the sum of squares for R times (10).

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func mapper(in chan int, out chan int) {
    for v := range in {out <- v*v}
}

func reducer(in1, in2 chan int, out chan int) {
    for i1 := range in1 {i2 := <- in2; out <- i1 + i2}
}

func main() {
    const N = 1024  // calculate sum of squares up to N; N must be power of 2
    const R = 10  // number of repetitions to fill the "pipe"

    var r [N*2]chan int
    for i := range r {r[i] = make(chan int)}
    var m [N]chan int
    for i := range m {m[i] = make(chan int)}

    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {go mapper(m[i], r[i + N])}
    for i := 1; i < N; i++ {go reducer(r[i * 2], r[i *2 + 1], r[i])}

    go func () {
        for j := 0; j < R; j++ {
            for i := 0; i < N; i++ {m[i] <- i + 1} 
        }
    } ()

    for j := 0; j < R; j++ {
        <- r[1]
    } 
}
```

The question is how to implement this mapreduce example in Haskell efficiently. The following Haskell code try to compute 10^2 + 7^2 in main function. My question is how to create an array (or a list) of channels, like Go, then connect mapper and reducer threads all together in the main function.

```
import Control.Concurrent
data MRchannel = MRchannel !(MVar MRcmd)
data MRcmd = Pass !Int | Add !Int
  deriving (Show)

mapper:: MRchannel -> MRchannel -> IO ()
mapper left_C@(MRchannel left) right_C@(MRchannel right) = do
    v <- takeMVar left
    case v of
        Pass x -> do
            putMVar right (Add (x*x))
            mapper left_C right_C
        otherwise -> do
            putStrLn "Error!"
            return ()

reducer::  MRchannel -> MRchannel -> MRchannel -> IO ()
reducer left_1_C@(MRchannel left_1) left_2_C@(MRchannel left_2) 
right_C@(MRchannel right) = do
    v1 <- takeMVar left_1
    case v1 of
        Add x1 -> do
            v2 <- takeMVar left_2
            case v2 of
                Add x2 -> do 
                    putMVar right (Add (x1+x2))
                    reducer left_1_C left_2_C right_C
                otherwise -> do
                    putStrLn "Error!"
                    return ()
        otherwise -> do
            putStrLn "Error!"
            return ()

main = do
m1_l <- newEmptyMVar
m2_l <- newEmptyMVar
r1_l1 <- newEmptyMVar
r1_l2 <- newEmptyMVar
r1_r <- newEmptyMVar
    let m1_input = MRchannel m1_l
    let m2_input = MRchannel m2_l
    let r1_input1 = MRchannel r1_l1
    let r1_input2 = MRchannel r1_l2
    let r1_output = MRchannel r1_r
    forkIO $ mapper m1_input r1_input1
    forkIO $ mapper m2_input r1_input2
    forkIO $ reducer r1_input1 r1_input2 r1_output

    putMVar m1_l (Pass 10)
    putMVar m2_l (Pass 7)

    y <- takeMVar r1_r
    case y of 
        Add kvalue  -> do
            putStrLn $ show kvalue
        otherwise -> do
            putStrLn "Error"
            return ()
```

Comment: can you describe in words what you want to compute ?

Comment: The GO program doesn't print anything; the haskell program in your answer keeps printing '358438400' endlessly. Could you describe what are you trying to compute? That said; it seems to me that the proper way would be to exploit haskell laziness (https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/loeb-moeb.md) and sprinkle it with `par`/`pseq` in the reducer.

Comment: Have a look at [`BoundedChan`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/BoundedChan-1.0.3.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-BoundedChan.html).

Comment: I am trying to calculate the sum of squares: 1^2+2^2+3^2....1024^2,  (N * (N + 1) * (2 * N + 1)) / 6. In order to test the performance of Go and Haskell, I repeat calculate the sum of squares for 10 times (R).

Comment: @PetrPudlák I have posted my solution in Haskell and I used MVar instead of BoundedChan. Do you mean BoundedChan is more efficient?

Comment: @user2336525 `MVar` allows you to store at most one value. So if a producer happens to be faster than a consumer, it'll block. With `BoundedChan` you can put more values into the channel, giving some buffer space when such a situation happens. | Note that for performance comparisons you're likely to get better numbers using [parallelization rather than concurrency](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/lang-parallel.html) - while very similar, they serve quite different use-cases.

Comment: While `MVar` is sufficient here, in general when you would use a channel in Go, you can use `Chan` or `BoundedChan` in Haskell, depending on the blocking behaviour you want. `MVar` is more for transferring ownership between threads of a single value at a time, or implementing higher-level concurrency abstractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative. It's not terribly elegant, but is a bit simpler than the original code, in my view.

Main changes:

- We do without having two lists of `MVars` and using the slow `!!`
- We use `forkAll` which spawns the whole binary tree of mappers/reducers (its argument is the depth: `2^10 = 1024`)
- `forkAll` is still suboptimal since it uses `++` which is slowish, though
- Major change: when doing `putMVar`, we force the value using `$!`, so that we do not store unevaluated expressions inside an `MVar`. This is a major performance boost.
- Instead of printing all the results, we only print their sum. Otherwise, text IO slows down the benchmark. (Note that the original `repeats` does `n+1` loops, so I had to use `10241` instead of `10240` below, to match the result.)

The new code is 54% faster, here.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

mapper :: MVar Int -> MVar Int -> IO ()
mapper left right = forever $ do
    v <- takeMVar left
    putMVar right $! v*v

reducer :: MVar Int -> MVar Int -> MVar Int -> IO ()
reducer left_1 left_2 right = forever $ do
    v1 <- takeMVar left_1
    v2 <- takeMVar left_2
    putMVar right $! v1+v2

forkAll :: Int -> MVar Int -> IO [MVar Int]
forkAll 0 res = do
  v <- newEmptyMVar
  _ <- forkIO $ mapper v res
  return [v]
forkAll depth res = do
  v1 <- newEmptyMVar
  r1 <- forkAll (depth - 1) v1
  v2 <- newEmptyMVar
  r2 <- forkAll (depth - 1) v2
  _ <- forkIO $ reducer v1 v2 res
  return (r1++r2)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  v <- newEmptyMVar
  res <- forkAll 10 v

  nums <- replicateM 10241 $ do
     mapM_ (\ (r,i) -> putMVar r (i+1)) $ zip res [0..]
     takeMVar v
  print $ sum nums
```

Comment: Thank you! The preliminary result for this new code is 8.823s. I compile it by using "ghc -threaded -o mr-opt --make -O -rtsopts mr-opt.hs".  However, the code I posted before is 1.307s. Do you get similar results?

Comment: After forcing the value using `$!`, the result goes from 1.307s to 1.095s.

Comment: @user2336525 I only tried compiling with `-O`. Without optimizations on, it is usually pointless to perform benchmarks, since there may be a large difference, as in this case. On my computer the code above runs in ~2.5s. The original code runs in ~6s.

Answer (score 1):

This returns the same as your Haskell code; as it is a pure computation, it uses `parallel` package.

```
import Data.Vector ((!), fromList, Vector)
import Control.Parallel (par, pseq)

reducer :: Int -> Int -> Int
reducer a b = a `par` b `pseq` a + b

result :: Vector Int -> Int
result src =
  let mr = fromList $
               map (\i arr -> reducer (arr ! (2 * i)) (arr ! (2 * i + 1))) [0..1023]
            ++ map (\i _ -> src ! i * src ! i) [0..1023]
            :: Vector (Vector Int -> Int)
      -- See https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/loeb-moeb.md
      res = fmap ($ res) mr
  in res ! 1

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let src = fromList [1..1024]
  print (result src)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out a solution in Haskell for this MapReduce example. Please point out if there is any part of this code can be optimized. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
import Control.Concurrent

mapper:: (MVar Int) -> (MVar Int) -> IO ()
mapper left right = do
    v <- takeMVar left
    --putMVar right (v*v)
    putMVar right $! v*v
    mapper left right

reducer::  (MVar Int) -> (MVar Int) -> (MVar Int) -> IO ()
reducer left_1 left_2 right = do
    v1 <- takeMVar left_1
    v2 <- takeMVar left_2
    --putMVar right  (v1+v2)
    putMVar right $! v1+v2
    reducer left_1 left_2 right        

repeats:: Int -> [MVar Int] -> [MVar Int] ->IO ()
repeats 0 m r = do        
    --mapM_ (\ x -> putMVar (m!!x) (x+1) ) [0..1023]
    mapM_ (\ (e,x) -> putMVar e (x+1)) $ zip m [0..]
    result <- takeMVar (r!!1)
    return ()
    --putStrLn (show result)

repeats n m r = do
    --mapM_ (\ x -> putMVar (m!!x) (x+1) ) [0..1023]
    mapM_ (\ (e,x) -> putMVar e (x+1)) $ zip m [0..]
    result <- takeMVar (r!!1)
    --putStrLn (show result)
    repeats (n-1) m r

main = do
    --m <- sequence $ take 1024 $ repeat newEmptyMVar
    m <- replicateM 1024 newEmptyMVar
    --r <- sequence $ take 2048 $ repeat newEmptyMVar
    r <- replicateM 2048 newEmptyMVar

    mapM_ (\ x -> forkIO (mapper (m!!x) (r!!(1024+x) ))) [0..1023]
    mapM_ (\ x -> forkIO (reducer (r!!(x*2)) (r!!(x*2+1))  (r!!x))) [0..1023]
    repeats 1024 m r
```

Comment: Minor point: `m <- replicateM 1024 newEmptyMVar`. Major point: don't loop over indices `[0..1023]` unless you really have to -- using `!!` later on is very inefficient (O(N^2))! Use instead `mapM_ (\ (e,x) -> putMVar e (x+1)) $ zip m [0..]` which is O(N)

Comment: @chi Thank you very much. I have modified my code according to your suggestions. It runs 10 times faster than the previous implementation.